Safari Audio Issues
I'm developing a music website and it's working perfectly on every device besides an iPhone. After looking around the internet im seeing all this stuff about autoplay restrictions and requiring a user interaction for audio to play but the thing is I already do?
So im completely at a loss ive tried looking around the internet, ive tried using the Web Audio API, ive tried asking AI for help and nothing. I'm not sure what to do. All code can be found at my Github Repo but here's the main code I think could be responsible for the issue.
https://github.com/colinguinane1/MusicPortfolio
useEffect(() => {
 const audio = audioRef.current;

 audio.src = currentSong;

 const handleTimeUpdate = () => {
 const remaining = audio.duration - audio.currentTime;
 setRemainingTime(remaining);
 setProgress((audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100);
    };

 audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeUpdate);
 audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
 setDuration(audio.duration);
    });

 if (isPlaying) {
 audio.play().catch((error) => {
 console.error("Playback error:", error);
 playButtonPressed = true;
      });
    } else {
 audio.pause();
    }

 return () => {
 audio.pause();
 audio.removeEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeUpdate);
    };
  }, [currentSong, isPlaying]);>

const handlePlay = () => {
 setIsPlaying(true);
 audioRef.current.muted = true; // Mute the audio initially
 audioRef.current
      .play()
      .then(() => {
 // After the play promise resolves, unmute the audio
 audioRef.current.muted = false;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
 console.error("Playback error:", error);
 playButtonPressed = true;
      });
  };>

I have already tried using the Web Audio API, I've tried different methods of playing my audio but I haven't gotten anything to work.
